# AngularJS - make constant/service/factory private for module

Tags: angularjs

I've run into a problem related to AngularJS. We have a main app, let's call it

```
angular.module('main');
```

This app imports other modules as dependencies:

```
angular.module('submodule1');
angular.module('submodule2');
```

In one of these modules I define a constant:

```
angular.module('submodule1').constant('CONST', 'foo');
```

After that, I use that constant in the module.
Now, my problem is the following: If the two submodules are injected as dependencies in module 'main', the constant 'CONST' can also be injected in 'submodule2'. This can lead to a lot of problems, especially if 'submodule2' also declared a constant named CONST with a different value.

So the question is... How can I make 'CONST' private only for 'submodule1' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because constants are global to the app, you need to have different names...

This might be a solution if you want the same names:

```
angular.module('submodule1')

.service('submodule1Constant',function(){
  //private 
  var CONST = "foo";

  this.get = function(){
    return CONST;
  };
})

.service('submodule2Constant',function(){
  //private 
  var CONST = "foo";

  this.get = function(){
    return CONST;
  };
});
```